# How to use Has One Of Many on a Many To Many relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have many to many relationship But I want to get only one record not a collection of records. I know it's possible to get only one record for a one to many relationship using the `latestOfMany()` function but it doesn't exist for a many to many one.

I ended up implementing it like this and I was wondering if there is a better way to have an actual relation function and not a getter function.

```
public function animal(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        fn () => $this->morphToMany(
            Animal::class,
            'follow_up',
            'animal_follow_ups',
            'follow_up_id',
            'animal_id'
        )->first()
    );
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you see with your current solution? Do you just want any one of the many animals?

Comment: @CalumHalpin since we already have the latestOfMany function to get only the latest of a collection of models in one to many relation, I thought there are also a similar function for a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

i think the purpose itself doesn't make any sense even when we use raw query to get a single result from many to many relationship, we should apply where condition to get it, or programatically we could apply iteration do get what we need... at least that what the documentation said here
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

hope it helps

Comment: But Laravel already has a function to get a single result from the multiple results in one to many relationship here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).